# I can't get my HTML alert banner to go under my header

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an alert banner under my header, but it won't show up. I've styled it in the CSS and coded it into the actual HTML, but it doesn't show up.

I've tried using `argin-top: 120px;` (120px is the height of my header) and it screwed up the header. I also tried `top: 120px;` but that did nothing. This is probably a simple fix, but I'm rather new to coding. Here is my HTML:

```css
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #0E6655;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.closebtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.closebtn:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span> My services are not impacted by the COVID-19 pandemic. Please refer to my <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Brett_Gee-103794371341643/">Facebook</a> for more info.
</div>
```

Comment: Is the alert inside the header? That makes a difference. Show us how the header and alert coexist.

Comment: @eskwayrd the alert <div> tag starts after the </header> tag

Comment: Please update your question to include the header. We need a [mcve]

Comment: @j08691 it won't let me edit the code without saying that it's not formatted correctly even when it is

Answer (score 0):

The above problem can be resolved through these 3 steps -

**Step 1:**  Update the CSS for the header to make sure that it always stays on top

**Step 2:**  Add the ID attribute to the alert-box element and use document.getElementById() to access the web element for an accurate result.

**Step 3:**  If the header has fixed position, then set fixed position, margin-top and z-index attributes to the alert-box, so that it will not get hidden behind the header.

**Here is the working code with document.getElementById used for finding and closing the alert-box element:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Alert - demo</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        
        <style>
            .alert {
                padding: 20px;
                background-color: #0E6655;
                color: white;                
                position: fixed;
                display: block;
                margin-top: 120px;
                z-index: 999;
            }

            .closebtn {
                margin-right: 20px;
                margin-left: 15px;
                color: white;
                font-weight: bold;
                float: right;
                font-size: 22px;
                line-height: 20px;
                cursor: pointer;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }

            .closebtn:hover {
                color: black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="border:1px solid #0E6655; width: 100%; height: 120px; position: fixed;"> 
            -- Header: 120 px height --
        </div>
        <div id="alert-box" class="alert">
            <span class="closebtn" onclick="document.getElementById('alert-box').style.display='none';">&times;</span>
            My services are not impacted by the COVID-19 pandemic. 
            Please refer to my 
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Brett_Gee-103794371341643/">
                Facebook
            </a> 
            for more info.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I tried using the ID attribute to the alert-box element and it still doesn't show. My header is at a fixed position.

Comment: If the header position is fixed, then the alert box must also be given fixed position, top margin and higher z-index value than that of the header, so that the alert box will not get overlapped or masked off by the header. I updated the code with changes required for fixed header.

Comment: that worked, thank you. How do I center the alert banner?